# Having rather in a sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, vocabulary

How and when do we use ***having rather*** in a sentence?

For example,

> The real evils, indeed, of Emma's situation were the power of ***having rather*** too much her own way, and a disposition to think a little too well of herself; these were the disadvantages which threatened alloy to her many enjoyments. The danger, however, was at present so unperceived, that they did not by any means rank as misfortunes with her.

Source: Emma by Jane Austen

Comment: It should be read as "having too much her own way". The word *rather* is just an adverb qualifying *too much*, with about the same meaning as *somewhat*, or *a bit*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase is **[get/have one's own way](https://www.lexico.com/definition/get_one%27s_own_way)**.

The author modifies it by adding *rather too much*.

*Rather* qualifies *too much* and means [*to a certain or significant extent or degree*](https://www.lexico.com/definition/rather). It might have been used to soften *too much* (to make it less assertive).

One might parse it as follows:

> the power of having rather too much her own way
>
> the power of having [rather too much] her own way
>
> the power of having [[rather] too much] her own way